# Pause and resume a spine animation

Tags: animation, libgdx

I am using [spine](http://esotericsoftware.com) in libgdx for animating characters. But I have some problems in it: How can I pause and resume an animation? Thanks for any help or example.

Comment: I never used `Spine`, but in the example in the documentation (http://de.esotericsoftware.com/spine-using-runtimes#Applying-animations) the `animationTime` is increased by `delta` and then `apply` is called with this time. I guess, if you just don't add the `delta`, the `Animation` should "pause". To resume it, just increase `animationTime` again.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Answer is something you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after exploring the superspineboy example. The answer is as simple as setting timeScale of animation to zero. TimeScale is a parameter of animation and used for changing the speed of animation. For Example if you set animation.timeScale = 2 it means that the animation would played 2 times faster, and of course if you set it to zero it will stopped. Nice Solution.

Comment: Did you try my "soltuion" to? Did that work to? If superspineboy uses this solution, i am sure it works good and is pretty clean, as the creator of superspineboy is the creator of Spine.

Comment: Yes it is a correct answer. But as you said the superspineboy solution is cleaner.